# 7zip - zip and encrypt entire directory of folders

Tags: encryption, directory, passwords, zip, 7zip

I am using the below code to batch zip an entire directory of folders.

```
for /d %%X in (*) do "c:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" a "%%X.zip" "%%X\"
```

Is there a way to incorporate an encryption option to this? I would like to add a unique password to each zip output file.

Comment: Can I assign a specific/unique password to use for each file?

Comment: I've added the -p option below - how would this be changed to assign a unique password?  When I kick off the .bat file it will assign the same password to all 100+ files it zips.     for /D %%d in (*.*) do "c:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" a "%%d.zip" -pTESTPW ".\%%d\*"

Comment: generate the pw separately, put it into a variable, then use that variable on the 7z.exe command line.